# Need to parse unmanaged JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have the JSON which have multiple properties and I am able to parse the JSON from C# code. The main problem is some time my JSON properties going change like

`"from":"Arun"` ====> No problem in this data

`"from":"{id: 1012718, links: {self: https://www.google.com}, mention_name: NeerajGupta, name: Neeraj Gupta, version: 00000000}"` =>Here is the problem and this is coming from third party API.

`"From":"Neeraj Gupta"` ====> Need this data from inner HTML

I need to parse the JSON inside JSON data.

OR

Can we read following string?

```
{id: 1012718, links: {self: https://www.google.com}, mention_name: NeerajGupta, name: Neeraj Gupta, version: 00000000}
```

Comment: The value of `from` for the second sample contains invalid json, therefore is not posible to parse with an strict parser

Comment: A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would help. But yes, you should try to make sure you have *valid* JSON. (Even `'from': 'Arun'` is invalid JSON, as its should use double quotes instead of apostrophes.)

Comment: is there are any option to read the id and name from inner json?

Comment: Is that _really_ what the data looks like?  As others have said, it's far from valid.  If it was valid, I'd say you just need to parse it twice - once to get the value of `from` as a string, then parse that again to get at the inner data.  If it really does look like that, the _best_ answer to this question is to go fix the source of the data, because it's not good.

Comment: You seem to not understand why is it invalid. For it to be valid every key and value (altought probably not 1012718) should be quoted

Comment: sorry for my mistake i have updated the double quotes!!!  I am getting this json from third party API. I can't change it. Do we have any alternate solution to hold the inner json in string variable and read any how?

Comment: And since the value of `from` is json itself the inner quotes should be escaped with `\"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank class in Visual Studio in your project. Copy the JSON data and then click EDIT > Paste Special > JSON as Class. It will create a respective JSON class as per your output. Then just parse the JSON using any JSON serializer and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix JSON first. Then you could parse it:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json =
            "{\"id\": \"1012718\", \"links\": {\"self\": \"https://www.google.com\"}, \"mention_name\": \"NeerajGupta\", \"name\": \"Neeraj Gupta\", \"version\": \"00000000\"}";
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);
        Console.WriteLine(data.name);
    }
}
}
```

If can not fix the input - you could try to parse it as a plain text instead.

Sample for a wrong JSON:

```
            string wrongJson =
            "{id: 1012718, links: {self: https://www.google.com}, mention_name: NeerajGupta, name: Neeraj Gupta, version: 00000000}";
        string key = " name: ";
        string part = wrongJson.Remove(0, wrongJson.IndexOf(key) + key.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(part);
        string result = part.Substring(0, part.IndexOf(","));
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: my JSON is comming from API so how can i change?

Comment: There are 2 cases: 1. You could ask your data source to fix the JSON. 2. You could parse it as a plain text. Just cut the string between "name:" and ","

Comment: Please take a look on a second sample. You could use RegExp or some other approach as well.